# How to combine two tensor in theano

Tags: python, theano

I am wondering how is it possible to combine two variables, similar to append in python? For example, we have two variables (after feeding with data):

x: with size 1*3
y: with size 1*3

now I want to have a variable, which combine x and y to a size of 1*3*2

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One can use [theano.tensor.stack](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.stack) to achieve this. Here's a working example:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as tt

x = tt.matrix()
y = tt.matrix()
z = tt.stack([x, y], axis=2)
f = theano.function([x, y], z)
print f([[1, 2, 3]], [[4, 5, 6]])
```

which prints

```
[[[ 1.  4.]
  [ 2.  5.]
  [ 3.  6.]]]
```